# A Trivial Pursuit #04 (Art and Literature 1/4): Threesome

Tags: word, knowledge, enigmatic-puzzle, letters, literature

<sub>This is part 4 of [A Trivial Pursuit](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?tab=newest&q=user%3a60644%20is%3aq%20%22a%20trivial%20pursuit%22&searchOn=3), a 25-part puzzle hunt. Each part is solvable on its own, with the exception of the meta-puzzle at the end.</sub>

---

| QUE | STI | ONS |
| --- | --- | --- |
| SEC@ND | L@TR | V@LUME |
| B@ANWELL’S | AUTHO@ | SISTE@S |
| H@LGA’S | F@LLOW | FOUND@RS |
| @AN’S | LANG@ON | @EBUT |
| @RALE | @OLD | @ASE |
| TRE@SURE | ISL@ND | @UTHOR |
| @USTEN | D@SHWOOD | ROM@NCE |
| DU@AS’ | @USKET | @EN |

| SOL | UTI | ONS |
| --- | --- | --- |
|  |  |  |
|  |  |  |
|  |  |  |
|  |  |  |
|  |  |  |
|  |  |  |
|  |  |  |
|  |  |  |

**The final answer is a relevant 8-letter word.** NB There is no [anagram](/questions/tagged/anagram) tag.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

First note that for each row, the @ represents the same symbol

> Which is in fact the **unique** common letter.

Each describes a three-word phrase:

> 1. Second LOTR Volume: **T**he **T**wo **T**owers (LOTR = [Lord of the Rings](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Lord_of_the_Rings))
>  2. Branwell's Author Sisters: Charlott**e**, **E**mily, Ann**e** (Sisters of [Branwell Brontë](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Branwell_Bront%C3%AB))
>  3. Helga's Fellow Founders: **R**owena, God**r**ic, Salaza**r** (Founders of the houses of [Hogwarts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hogwarts#History) in the Harry Potter series)
>  4. Dan's Langdon Debut: A**n**gels a**n**d Demo**n**s (First Dan Brown book featuring [Robert Langdon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robert_Langdon_(book_series)))
>  5. Crale Cold Case: F**i**ve L**i**ttle P**i**gs (Agatha Christie [novel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Five_Little_Pigs) about the murder of Amyas Crale)
>  6. Treasure Island Author: R**o**bert L**o**uis Stevens**o**n ([No explanation required](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robert_Louis_Stevenson))
>  7. Austin Dashwood Romance: Se**n**se a**n**d Se**n**sibility (Romantic [novel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sense_and_Sensibility) by Jane Austen featuring the Dashwood sisters)
>  8. Dumas' Musket Men: Atho**s** Portho**s** Arami**s** ([The Three Musketeers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Three_Musketeers))

Note that for each three-word phrase, there is exactly one (unique!) common letter among the three words, which spells:

> [ternions](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/ternion) (which is really neat since it means 'groups of three')

Comment: This is indeed the correct answer. Note that the at signs are a bit more specific than just 'representing the same symbol'... It's rot13(sgd nmkx bnllnm kdssdq zbqnrr zkk sgqdd), a nod to the solution method...

Comment: @Stiv ah yes. Which I must acknowledge that this makes the puzzle much more difficult to set so kudos to you. Also ur prev comment is in rot1 not rot 13. (Do i get a tick:)? )

Comment: Ha, good spot - I was using different settings on rot13.com for another purpose earlier and forgot to set it back...!

Comment: @Stiv do I need to add your rot13 comment to get the full tick/answer accepted?

Comment: That would round it out nicely. Perhaps it might be worth emphasising the letters of interest in the solutions too, to make them stand out (e.g. in bold font). Otherwise a reader has to go back and forth between the two spoilers after reading your final answer and try and make the connection for themselves - help them to see it more easily... :)

Comment: The checkmark is yours :) (I just added some explanatory links and corrected a couple of minor typos and detail inaccuracies...) Well done!

Comment: And now... you deserve... a lafetime speaking that way!